# Show historical changes for custom record entries

Tags: netsuite

I have created a custom record to show a list of laptops issued in the company and their current holders. I also need to show the historical changes to this custom record, for example if the laptop holder changes on a particular date, the record should show me historical changes as well. Is this possible using custom records?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The custom record has a setting named "ENABLE SYSTEM NOTES" in the UI, when this box is checked it enables system notes (ref [Suite Answer 85771](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/85771/kw/85771)).  To see historical information on the record itself you can look at the "System Notes" tab.  To do this via saved search, create a Custom Record type saves search and use the "System Notes Fields..." option in the criteria or results tab.  You can even schedule the saved search to i.e. send an email each time the "Holder" changes.  For more information on Saved Searches, reference [Suite Answer 8493](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8493/kw/8493)